# Terrain and satellite view using MapKit

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am new to Mapkit View. I want to display when I give lat and long without destination.
Is it possible to display maps through terrain, satellite view in MapKit? Any tutorial link? I have seen some examples with accessing Google map API (html file). Is it necessary?

Answer (score 9):

Or You can set it Programmatically as

```
mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
```

if not supported in Swift 3 try this:

```
    map.mapType = MKMapType.satellite;
```

Answer (score 8):

If you add a mapkit view on to your xib, you will see on the properties that you can set it to sattelite, terrain or map.  The best tutorial/ link that I have found regarding mapkit is here:

[Link](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=65)

Comment: Should not that there is no "Terrain" support in MapKit - only Map, Satellite, and Hybrid

Comment: My apologies, you are right.  I often get terrain and sattelite mixed in my head.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 4):

You can set any of the following `Map Type` for `MapView`

```
map.mapType = MKMapType.hybrid
map.mapType = MKMapType.hybridFlyover
map.mapType = MKMapType.mutedStandard
map.mapType = MKMapType.satellite
map.mapType = MKMapType.satelliteFlyover
map.mapType = MKMapType.standard
```

- **Hybrid** - A satellite image of the area with road and road name information layered on top.
- **Standard** - A street map that shows the position of all roads and some road names..
- **Satellite** - Satellite imagery of the area.
- **HybridFlyover** - A hybrid satellite image with flyover data where available.
- **SatelliteFlyover** - A satellite image of the area with flyover data where available.
- **MutedStandard** - A street map where your data is emphasized over the underlying map details.

`hybrid , satellite , standard` are available for **iOS 3** and above

`hybridFlyover , satelliteFlyover` are available for **iOS 9** and above

`mutedStandard` are available for **iOS 11** and above

Answer (score 3):

This is perhaps different with Objective-C, but in Swift it would be one of the following (add to viewDidLoad(), for instance):

```
mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard;  // default: road map
mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Satellite;
mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid;
```