# Swift 4 MKMapView change map style like GoogleMap

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit, mkmapview, swift4

I am using MKMapView in my application. Now I want to change map style to dark theme.

In GoogleMap we can change style of map. So How can I achieve style in MKMapView.

Please help me.

Comment: You mean MapType of Map View ?

Comment: check for the `mapType` property

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47669985/4608334 for changing MapType of MapView

Comment: @ReinierMelian I want to change mapstyle. Like I want to set JSON file as style.

Comment: @VinothVino I want to change mapstyle. Like I want to set JSON file as style

Comment: See my answer. I hope that helps you to implement dark theme for MapView @EktaPadaliya

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the `Dark Theme` in **MapView** using `Google Maps API`. 
Have a look at this documentation for styling the `MapView` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/styling.

With **Google Maps APIs Styling Wizard**, you can customize themes, roads, labels etc. Then add a new file to your project named `style.json` and paste this custom style.

See the below link for selecting map themes such as `Standard, Dark, Silver, Night, Retro` etc. Take a look at https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com to create map style for `MapView`.

Here's the [sample repository](https://github.com/googlemaps/maps-sdk-for-ios-samples) on GitHub, it demonstrate the use of styling the MapView. See this [medium post](https://medium.com/@ortizfernandomartin/customize-mapkits-mkmapview-with-google-maps-styling-wizard-a5dcc095e19f) too

Answer (score 0):

In MKMapView you are not able to change the apple's map theme. You can change the map type:
Example for satellite :

`self.mapView?.mapType = .satellite`

You can also use tiles from a different provider.

```
class YourMapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mapView : MKMapView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.mapView?.delegate = self
        self.tilesRenderer.reloadData()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    lazy var tilesRenderer : MKTileOverlayRenderer! = {

        let urlTemplate = "The tiles URL"  // URL template is a string where the substrings "{x}", "{y}", "{z}", and "{scale}" are replaced with values from a tile path to create a URL to load. For example: http://server/path?x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&scale={scale}.
        let overlay = MKTileOverlay.init(urlTemplate: urlTemplate)
        overlay.isGeometryFlipped = false
        overlay.canReplaceMapContent = true
        self.mapView?.add(overlay, level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveLabels)

        let renderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer.init(tileOverlay: overlay)
        return renderer
    }()

    public func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer{

        return self.tilesRenderer
    }
}
```

An other alternative could be to use the GoogleMap iOS SDK:
[GoogleMaps iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/ios/?hl=fr)

Comment: I wan to apple JSON fine to map style.

Comment: You mean you want to get the style from a JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

you can get too many custom styles json file from snazzy maps

https://snazzymaps.com/

Comment: How would you integrate into your application. Its a json file. What steps would I have to take?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this github repo.

https://github.com/fmo91/MapKitGoogleStyler